# Downloading part of guava-libraries

Tags: java, guava

Current version (14.0.1) of guava-libraries is 2 MB. It is not huge, it is not small neither. Especially when I want to use it in an exemplary project for my students and only need "Strings" part of it for parsing some input.

Are there any smaller parts of Guava available as JAR-s with compiled code, or I have to use all of it, or compile and prepare my own bundle (e.g. [using ProGuard](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava))?

Comment: As you noticed, ProGuard is the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1) there does not seem to be any smaller jar files that the Guava library is depending on.

So I would say no, there are no smaller portions of the Guava library that you can use. You will have to build your own jar files with only the classes you need.

So ProGuard seems to be the right solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and succeeded with ProGuard. However, there is a dependency on javax.inject in Guava, so ProGuard configuration has to be modified (see my comment on the page mentioned in the question).